# Prove that a function does not decrease

Tags: calculus

Let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be **convex** and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}f(x)=0$.

How do I prove that $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ does not decrease in $(0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $g(x) = f(x)/x$ is the slope of the secant line through $(0, 0)$ and $\bigl(x, f(x)\bigr)$.